# What's correct BLASTER variable for my sound card?

Tags: audio-hardware, quake

I want to play Quake in its (not so) original realm, but I have a problem. I cannot play with sound because my BLASTER environment variable (found in readme.txt) is incorrect.

What's correct BLASTER variable value for Realtek High Definition Audio?

Comment: on a related note, it is finally [legal to sell quake in Germany](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/114481-Germany-Unbans-Quake)

Comment: Yeah, hood luck with that.  Most modern sound cards don't have Sound Blaster emulation any more, since most games made in the last **16 years** were for Windows.

Comment: @Powerlord good thing there's DOSBOX

Comment: @TobiasKienzler He already said he doesn't want to run it in DOSBox.

Comment: I have also read that "Realtek does not fully support SoundBlaster features." so there might not be a correct setting.

Answer (score 7):

I found a good reference to what the BLASTER environment variable is looking for at [this link](http://www.rinkworks.com/apogee/s/6.4.2.shtml).  To determine these parameters you're going to have to check the set up of your card ... this was always the hardest part of getting these games to run correctly.

Alternately you could load Quake in DOSBOX and not worry about it.

```
SET BLASTER=A220 I5 D1 T3 P330 H6 E620
 |    |     |    |  |  |  |    |  |
 |    |     |    |  |  |  |    |  |_______ AWE 32 Only Parameter
 |    |     |    |  |  |  |    |__________ "High" DMA Channel
 |    |     |    |  |  |  |_______________ MIDI Port
 |    |     |    |  |  |__________________ Type of Card
 |    |     |    |  |_____________________ DMA Channel
 |    |     |    |________________________ Interrupt
 |    |     |_____________________________ Port Address
 |    |___________________________________ Environment Variable
 |________________________________________ DOS Command
```

Comment: Type = 1 for emulated soundblaster...

Answer (score 4):

While you could probably solve this particular problem and get a little bit closer to running Quake, you're likely to run into further problems later on down the road.  It's a lot of work that can be easily avoided!

I'm going to suggest trying one of the many [Quake clients](http://quakeone.com/files/1-quake-clients/) that have been updated since the open source release of the [Quake engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quake_engine) years ago.

There's probably at least one that keeps the same graphic quality as the original Quake, although if you don't mind it being a bit fancier, that's certainly possible as well.  They all should support the levels/enemies/etc of the original Quake, and you'll need the PAK files that came with your original release in order to play them.

[DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=653&letter=Q) is probably a good secondary app to look into, if you're a bit more interested in playing the game in all its former DOS glory.

Comment: No, I'm not going to try any source ports or DOSBox, and Quake runs perfectly with -nosound in DOS (from boot floppy) on my computer.

Comment: Best of luck then :)

Comment: @SiPlus you just made me realize I havent't tried running DOS natively since two PCs...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading [WinQuake](ftp://ftp.idsoftware.com/idstuff/quake/wq100.zip) from id Software's ftp site instead.

> WinQuake (WQ) is a native Win32 version of Quake, and will run on
>   either Win95 or Windows NT 4.0 or later.  It is designed to take
>   advantage of whatever enhanced video, sound, and input capabilities
>   (such as DirectX or VESA VBE video modes) are present, but has
>   fallback functionality so it can run on any Win95 or NT 4.0 or later
>   system, even if neither DirectX nor VESA VBE is available.  You may
>   experience problems running WQ on some systems, because driver and
>   operating-system support for game functionality are not yet mature
>   under Win32, and many bugs and incompatibilities remain in those
>   components.  If you encounter what seems to be a bug, first please
>   check through the list of known problems, below.  If your problem
>   doesn't appear on the list, please fill out and submit the WQ bug
>   report at http://www.idsoftware.com/contact/.

Granted, WinQuake was released in 1997, so no guarantees that it will still run.

WinQuake requires that you already have Quake installed to run (just like QuakeWorld or GLQuake).

Answer (score -2):

best bet is to buy a soundblaster 16 card. can find em for like 5 bucks, most of the ones left on ebay are actually only emulations of opl3. if you own a laptop though you're basically screwed. wavetable synthesis ruined video game music and put the tracking community back a decade.

Comment: How do you propose to put an old ISA card in a motherboard with no ISA slots?